# GridBagLayout with JPanels

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I've searched for hours now but still can't find the answer I need.

So I'm trying to set up an easy Layout and all I want is a GridBagLayout 
which contains two JPanels. The build Layout should look like on the Image
below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Most likely nobody will start coding your work for you here.

Comment: The answer to what? What's your problem? Where are you stuck? Everything you need is explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html , the first place to go that you will surely already have read after hours of investigation. Now, what is not clear?

Comment: A grid bag layout can work for this, the left panel would have gridx=0 and the right would have gridx=1. You can get the different sizes with the weightx field of GridBagConstraints. As @Zavior said, go and try this and post your explicit question/where you are getting stuck and I'd be happy to help more.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to add my code :(

Comment: But I am really happy for "user and"'s awenser! Thank you a lot. This is an awesome community!!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v got it using BoxLayout.

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class ProportionalPanels extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ProportionalPanels() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    final JPanel panel_A = new JPanel();
    panel_A.setBackground(new Color(255, 165, 0));
    contentPane.add(panel_A);

    final JPanel panel_B = new JPanel();
    panel_B.setBackground(new Color(176, 196, 222));
    contentPane.add(panel_B);

    panel_A.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    panel_B.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));

    panel_A.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    panel_B.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));

    panel_A.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE / 5, Short.MAX_VALUE));
    panel_B.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("Panel width rate: %.2f %n",
                    panel_B.getSize().width / (double) panel_A.getSize().width);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProportionalPanels frame = new ProportionalPanels();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: If it really helped you could also mark answer as useful)